# Building Blender 2.6x on Mac OS 10.8: 3DconnexionClient/ConnexionClientAPI.h'

Tags: xcode, blender

I am trying to play around with the sources of blender and try to follow the tutorial on http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Mac

I am using the CMake+Xcode method which works up to the step where it says "select install" as target and hit the run button.  After 3-4 minutes I get this error:

```
CompileC /Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.o intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/Jan/blender-build/blender
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wno-arc-abi -Wno-c++11-extensions "-DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D__SSE__ -D__MMX__ -D__SSE2__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -DOPJ_STATIC -DWITH_INPUT_NDOF -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/lib/Debug/include -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/intern/ghost -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/intern/string -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/source/blender/imbuf -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/source/blender/makesdna -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/extern/glew/include -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/lib/Debug -msse2 -msse -pipe -funsigned-char -DGHOST_COCOA -DUSE_QTKIT -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.dia -c /Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.mm -o /Users/Jan/blender-build/cmake/intern/ghost/Blender.build/Debug/bf_intern_ghost.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.o

/Users/Jan/blender-build/blender/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_NDOFManagerCocoa.mm:30:11: fatal error: '3DconnexionClient/ConnexionClientAPI.h' file not found
        #include <3DconnexionClient/ConnexionClientAPI.h>
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

As I own a SpaceNavigator, the drivers are installed and they are definitely found under /Library/Frameworks/3DconnexionClient.framework and also the searched header file is available.

I also tried to add the header+library search paths but that doesn't work either.

Any help on that?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No. Basically, the render community was the worst experience I've ever encountered.